# Free -vs- Purchase App for iPad/iPhone question

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I need some help/clarification on how the paid vs free works. I have an App and I have a free version with ads.  When the user purchases I want to disable the ads... that's no problem.  But, how do I know they purchased?  When the user goes to the App store, to purchase do I get an e-mail, or anything that I can key off of?  I do not want to have two versions and if I do, how does Apple evaluate both? I am ready to submit the App, but I am confused on how I transition from free to paid.

I hope this makes sense and someone can clarify the process for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use inApp purchase or compile a different version that will have a price and sell it separately.

Comment: Ok, so inApp purchase, I will search around on that topic, but my question still goes unanswered.  I cannot believe I am the only App developer who wants to convert the app from free to paid.

Comment: Thing is, you may not modify the App in any means after you put it up in the App Store. That is part of the aproval guidelines. https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html You either supply a paid version as different App, that get sold separately, or you use inApp purchase. Booth methods are commonly used, especial for games.

Comment: Here: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/inapppurchase/  (Good luck with your sales :) )

Comment: Well, I may have missed it in my reading, but even if I use inApp Purchase, how can I tell if the user paid so that I can programmatically disable the ads?  That is my confusion.

Comment: Follow my link. There are several links about this topic. Basically your App talks to the App store when the user wants it and your App can unlock now whatever you sold. It is more work to set that up, but it is also the most elegant way. Laziness of the devs is the reason why you see more programs using 'Free' versions that require the user to log again to the store and buy the full product. Laziness of the user has it, that inApp sells better then asking the user to actively buy a full version, so the more work pays of.

Comment: Ok GREAT!  I think that answers my question.  I am going through inApp purchase now and I thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

@Helge is right. You can do it either through In-App purchase or a separate app version.

If you want to knw about In-App purchase pls go through this [Tutorial](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/)